# What full-size tripods are shortest when folded?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, tripod

I don't ever bring my old tripod with me, not because it's too heavy, but because it doesn't fit into my bag...

So: are there any full-size tripods that fold down to, say, 35cm or less? (Extra information: it needs to support at least 1kg, and by full-size I mean at least 1m and preferably taller)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have a [Velbon CX Mini](http://www.velbon.co.uk/newvelbon/pages/CXminiF.html) that folds to 30 cm, but it only gets 64 cm tall.

The [Velbon V-Pod](http://www.velbon.co.uk/newvelbon/pages/vpod.html) folds to 29 cm and reaches 101 cm, according to their specifications.

Manfrotto doesn't seem to have anything that folds to less than 42 cm.

Comment: Actually, it looks as though Velbon have a whole bunch of tripods that might do the trick - thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Three Legged Thing? http://www.3leggedthing.com

They have an excellent tripod range. One of their best is called 'Brian';
http://www.3leggedthing.com/brianevo2blue.html